# Groupby one column if string contained and get maximum values of another column in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, plyr

Given a dataframe as follows:

```
df <- structure(list(city = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("bj", "sh"), class = "factor"), type = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("buy_area", "buy_price", 
"sale_area", "sale_price"), class = "factor"), value = c(1200L, 
800L, 1900L, 1500L, 15L, 10L, 17L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Out:

[image]

How could I obtain maximum values from `value` column for 2 types of `type`: `area` and `price` contained respectively.

The expected results will be two values: `1900` for **area** and `17` for **price**.

To groupby `type` and get maximum of `value`s we can use:

```
ddply(df, .(variable), summarise, max.value = max(value))
```

**Update:** output of @det's solution:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create column that categorize `type` into area or price and group by that column:

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    type2 = case_when(
      str_detect(type, "_area$") ~ "area",
      str_detect(type, "_price$") ~ "price",
      TRUE ~ NA_character_
    )
  ) %>%
  group_by(type2) %>%
  summarise(max_value = max(value))
```

output:

```
  type2 max_value
  <chr>     <int>
1 area       1900
2 price        17
```

Comment: It seems only generate one maximum value.

Comment: it returns `data.frame` that contains maximum values for required group in column `max_value`

Comment: Please check the update in the post, how could I get maximum values for area and price respectively?

Comment: try putting `dplyr::summarise` insted `summarise`

Answer (score 1):

Update: This one is more concise (it is a small modification of Ronak Shah's answer:

```
df %>% 
    separate(type, c("sale_buy", "area_price")) %>% 
    group_by(area_price) %>% 
    summarise(max = max(value))
```

Output:

```
  area_price   max
  <chr>      <int>
1 area        1900
2 price         17
```

First answer:
one way could be:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(type) %>% 
    summarise(max = max(value)) %>% 
    filter(grepl("sale", type))
```

Output:

```
  type         max
  <fct>      <int>
1 sale_area   1900
2 sale_price    17
```

Comment: I think we should grepl `area` and `price`, rather than `sale`, no?

Comment: with `filter(grepl("sale", type))` we search for values that contain "sale" as string and keep this rows in the type column. I thought this was the expected output. If you remove the filter line you may get a clue why this was. Anyway you can adapt as desired. By the way a good question (upvote!)

Answer (score 1):

Divide the `type` column in two columns and find max by group.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate(type, c('type', 'col'), sep = '_') %>%
  group_by(col) %>%
  summarise(value = max(value, na.rm = TRUE))

#  col   value
#  <chr> <int>
#1 area   1900
#2 price    17
```

You can also extract `'area'` or `'price'` from `type` and use it as grouping column.

```
df %>%
  group_by(type = stringr::str_extract(type, 'area|price')) %>%
  summarise(value = max(value, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to use `area` and `price` in the code since in my real data, there is no seperator `_`. :(

Comment: In that case, you can extract area or price value from `type` column. see the updated answer.

Comment: Very concise and beautiful answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df %>% separate(type,c("type","area")) %>% group_by(area) %>% filter(value == max(value,na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: `c("type","area")`, or `c("price","area")`?

Comment: the data frame I got was sale_area , buy_area etc... i thought that when you specified the need to show only max values the type column was irrelevant. So i separated them.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Duly Noted your suggestion, thanks @gerhard